# Help with Chinese painting marks please

Tags: character-identification

Please can anyone help identify what is written on this painting and the accompanying marks / seals please? I’ve tried to research this but the amount of information is overwhelming! Any help Gratefully received! Thank you.
[image]!
[image]

Comment: if you suspect this painting is valuable, contact the sotheby’s or christie’s

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for such an in depth reply! So helpful, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

the top seal is “張爰㞢印”, you may compare the small seal character:

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=張](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%BC%B5)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=爰](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%88%B0)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=㞢](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E3%9E%A2)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=印](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8D%B0)

roughly, it means the seal of “張爰”

the bottom one is “大千”

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=大](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%A4%A7)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=千](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8D%83)

[張大千](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang_Dai-chien), a famous artist in the last century

the top five bigger characters are :番女掣厖啚 (last character, actually is a variant not yet have a unicode code point)

[image]

https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAwNzM5LTAwMQ

the following characters are:

甲x嘉平月蜀郡張爰大千父

“嘉平月” is the last month of the chinese calendar, roughly mid-december to mid-february

“蜀郡” is sichuan

“張爰大千父” is name of the author

甲x, well it must be the one of the sexagenary cycle. unfortunately i can’t recognise the x at this moment